# Export template haskell generated definitions

Tags: haskell, code-generation, template-haskell

My module contains definitions, part of which are exported (in `module` clause). I want to export Template Haskell-generated declarations too. But since there is seemingly no way to modify `module` clause with TH, I cannot do this.

Is it possible to specify that TH-generated declarations should be exported at all? Or maybe there are other ways to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to export the names of the generated TH declarations. For example, if you have a TH function that generates a `data B = C | D` declaration, you need to simply export `module Mymodule (B(C,D)) where ...`.

If you don't specify an export list, all declarations in that module will be exported. What you can do as a little trick is to put all of your generated TH functions in one module, and then reexport that module:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
-- Put all of the generated stuff in one module
module Bla.Generated where

generateAFunctionCalled "foo"
generateAFunctionCalled "bar"

-- Re-export the generated module
module Bla (module Bla.Generated) where
import qualified Bla.Generated
```

This has the disadvantage that you can't put haddock documentation for generated functions, but that's not something you usually do anyways.

Comment: Problem is that there are a *lot* of names, and they themselves are generated, so enumerating them in export list is not an option. Well, I think I'll stick with export list absence for now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Vladimir: If you want to export all the TH definitions, but not other definitions, couldn't you use this solution and `import Bla.Generated hiding (...)` ? That way the things you don't exclude all get exported...

Comment: The point was that the `.Generated` module only contains TH generated stuff. The normal `Bla` module would contain other stuff that you would/maybe would not like to export.