# How to automatically export modified with fclabels data fields?

Tags: haskell

For example if I have:

fclabels on hackage: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fclabels

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell, TypeOperators #-}
module Yaml
  ( Config(..) )
  where

data Config = Config { _a :: String }

$(mkLabel ''Config)
```

`_a` is exported because of `Config(..)` there in line 3, I can also add `a` there for manual exporting but is it possible to export all generated with `mkLabel` fields automatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export template haskell generated definitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672981/export-template-haskell-generated-definitions)

Comment: This seems like it would be a problem for anything using template haskell, not just fclabels.